# Cakephp check if smtp email is valid

Tags: validation, email, cakephp, smtp, cakephp-2.0

Is there anyway in cake php to check whether smtp setup is valid or not (port number, host name, user and password) are all valid and email will eventually get send, before it even try to send.

```
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
$email = new CakeEmail();
$email->config(array(
    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'port'=>25, //this port number is wrong
    'timeout'=>30,              
    'username'=>'abc@gmail.com',
    'password'=>'wrong password',
    'transport'=> 'Smtp',
)); 

$email->from('abc@gmail.com');
$email->to($recipient);
$email->subject($final_subject);
$email->send()
```

is there anyway to check the $email->config, is valid and $email->send will be succesfull? or error?
I would like to verified the config before $email->send().. any help?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Exception handling. It will give you an appropriate message that what you are doing wrong:

```
try {    
$email->from('abc@gmail.com');
$email->to($recipient);
$email->subject($final_subject);
$email->send()
}
catch(Exception $e) {
pr($e);die;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`is there anyway to check the $email->config, is valid and $email->send will be succesfull?`

unfortunately, no.

smtp means Simple Mail Transfer Protocol, it's protocol, email will be sent by  email server (which can be deployed on another physical server), so, correct configuration does not get you guaranties that email will be sent successfully. Also, correct configuration does not get you guaranties that email will be delivered successfully.